# AngularJS / CORS OPTIONS request and performance

Tags: angularjs, http, cors

I'm making a cross-domain CORS POST request in AngularJS as follows:

```
var url = 'https://api.myapp.tld';
var userObj = { username:'foo', password: 'bar' };

$http.post(url,userObj).success(function(data){
  // do success stuff
}).error(function(data){
  // do FAIL stuff
});
```

As per [the standard](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) Angular will 'preflight' this with an `OPTIONS` request. My server returns a 204 header with the requisite access-control headers to allow the client continue. So far so good.

However this happens before *every* `POST` request, unless they occur in very quick succession in which case I can get a few in a row (so it seems there's some sort of timeout maybe). My app is a mobile web app so I worry that these extra options requests could negatively impact performance over 3G (or Edge) networks.

My question is: Can the server's response to the options request indicate to the client that it can store the rules for a longer period?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular doesn't need this configuration--your server needs to add the proper cache headers on the `OPTIONS` request. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Max-Age

Comment: Thanks! Yes just found it too: The `Access-Control-Max-Age` header does what I need.

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid the preflight request altogether if you are willing to alter your API a bit so that common endpoints are considered "simple requests".

I've got a post covering all the restrictions and how to get around them called [Two Strategies for Crossing Origins with Performance in Mind](https://gooroo.io/GoorooTHINK/Article/16408/Two-Strategies-for-Crossing-Origins-with-Performance-in-Mind/19880#.VpfNVlmo3eE).